# Shell script to get file count of directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, debian

I am trying to create a shell script that will get the count of files in a static directory, then display the Directory and the number of files it contains in a table. Here is the setup I have so far.

File containing static paths of directories. The file is called dirs.txt. These are written as.
`/path/to/file.txt`

Here is the script that I am running:

```
#! /bin/bash

files=$(wc -l)

while read dir; do
print_table() {
  perl -MText::ASCIITable -e '
    $t = Text::ASCIITable->new({drawRowLine => 1});
    while (defined($c = shift @ARGV) and $c ne "--") {
      push @header, $c;
      $cols++
    }
    $t->setCols(@header);
    $rows = @ARGV / $cols;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
      for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        $cell[$i][$j] = $ARGV[$j * $rows + $i]
      }
    }
    $t->addRow(\@cell);
    print $t' -- "$dir"
}

print_table Directory    'Files Created' -- \
            $dir "${files}"

done < dirs.txt
```

I am wanting to do a "foreach" so that all of the folder paths can be added to the same table with their respective file counts.

The issue is that when I run this, it just hangs. If I enter the directory individually as a variable and remove the "for" "do", then it works.

Comment: Are you expecting this script to receive something on stdin? `files=$( wc -l )` is going to hang until you give it something on stdin if you don't provide a file as an argument.

Comment: No. That was one of the issues that was identified and was a complete oversight on my part. I am wanting to provide it a list of static directories to check. The fix that was mentioned by @DanielHao seems to have mostly fixed this. Now I am trying to get all of the entries added to one table.